# What do I need to know to make a basic Django website?

Tags: python, django

As the title states, I am curious what I need to know to make a website with Django.

My Attempts:
    I am familiar with Python, but despite my attempts to begin work on a webpage(attempted some Django tutorials online and purchased "2 Scoops of Django" and started to work with some of its recommendations) I always feel like it points me at something else to learn. (PostgreSQL, git, virtualenv, VirtualBox, Vagrant, and more.) I understand that some of these are tools I just need to implement, but I feel as if I could delve into these much further and don't understand when I should stop trying to learn more about these.

My Goal:
    I want to be able to develop a webpage with Django, and understand the steps and tools I am implementing.

My Question:
    What tools do I need to learn, and how much about them do I need to learn to be able to begin working effectively with Django?

Comment: Well, there is a tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/, which helped me a lot... Learn python(mostly), html, css.... Hard to answer

Comment: '2 Scoops of Django' is not a good book for beginners, it's good to learn some practical approaches after you've already learnt how to make Django projects that work. There was 'A defenitive guide to Django' which is perfect for beginners, but I guess it's outdated now and you could learn pretty much the same via [Django Getting Started](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/) and then more from [Topics section of Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/). Other than that, read some blogs on Django development and practice via trial and error.

Comment: You don't really have to learn Postgres (basic understanding of common SQL is enough), VirtualBox, Vagrnant, etc. at the beginning as you can do well without them for simple projects. virtualenv/pyvenv - you can do without it, but learning a couple of basic commands is easy and it is used for all Python development, not just Django. git - version control, again you can do without it just creating copies of your work folder, but it's better to learn it at basic level - about a dozen commands and understanding of branching. In general all you need is Python knowledge as Django is just Python.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question but I can try to answer it as clearly as possible.

You said you are familiar with Python, that's a good thing. The next thing you should know is the MVC framework that Django is based on and uses extensively.

You can refer to Django tutorial here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/ (as already mentioned)

I can give you a TLDR of how this can work:
1. Create a django project : $ django-admin startproject mysite
2. In the file structure that is created, the most important things would be:
   a. models.py - your database models or schema defined as classes and objects
   b. views.py - the view you are trying to display (mainly rendering .html in your case)
   c. settings.py - you path, app setting, permissions, etc
   d. urls.py - how you will be calling your specific views (redirect urls)

3. Once you write a basic app, try to run it using $python manage.py runserver and voila!

For the website part, there a few easy ways. You can download twitter bootstrap and try to attempt a simple page that you can find online with django http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

As far as technologies go:
venv: is so that you do not mess up your other python, etc versions on your laptop, it isn't necessary
git: this is something you should learn irrespective of a project requirement. There are basic 3 commands that will be enough.

You might have to learn basics of HTML and CSS for manipulating your own website. Most of the backend can be handled on Django using objects of models you created.

Try these things out and let me know if you need anymore information.